# No puedo llegar a la url de un mongodb-express contenerizado en ejecución

Tags: mongodb, docker

He intentado lanzar un contenedor mongo-express para poder ver mi base de datos mongodb:

```
C:\Users\antoi>docker run -d ^
More? -p 8081:8081 ^
More? -e  ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin ^
More? -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password ^
More? --net mongo-network ^
More? --name mongo-express ^
More? -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb ^
More? mongo-express
9ea974d79f1823119556f72ca728c4e0d47de784547b7cec8166de9579aa88f2
```

Pero no hay conexión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí están los contenedores en funcionamiento

```
C:\Users\antoi>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                                  NAMES
c94579a6588b   mongo          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   30 hours ago   Up 22 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp          bold_saha
7afdce3a7634   09361feeb475   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 days ago     Up 3 days       33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp, :::3307->3306/tcp   etl_db
```

Parece que mi contenedor no está ahí.

Aqui esta la salida de docker network ls:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Docker\techworld-js-docker-demo-app\app>docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                                   DRIVER    SCOPE
aa6f224c5761   bridge                                 bridge    local
c724a97b5c47   data-tools_default                     bridge    local
32e53773e63b   host                                   host      local
9209928de393   mongo-network                          bridge    local
51cfa1d3306d   none                                   null      local
9091d583e4eb   techworld-js-docker-demo-app_default   bridge    local
```

En efecto, hizo `docker create mongo-network`

Aqui estan las imagenes disponibles:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Docker\techworld-js-docker-demo-app>docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
data-tools_etl      latest    73306695e8a2   10 days ago    607MB
mongo-express       latest    dc564d602ca5   11 days ago    136MB
mongo               latest    269b735e72cb   2 weeks ago    682MB
mysql               5.7       09361feeb475   2 months ago   447MB
metabase/metabase   latest    79b9026b1454   2 months ago   408MB
alpine/git          latest    b8f176fa3f0d   3 months ago   25.1MB
```

Comment: ¿Es posible que no estén en la misma network?

Comment: Sí, esto es posible @S.Wasta , pero pensé que había resuelto este error poniendo una red común que se puede ver en la salida de `docker network ls` que acabo de anadir. En efecto cree `mongo-network` para esto

Comment: Lo más fácil es hacerlo con `docker-compose`, estoy viendo a escribirte los comandos

Comment: Parece que ningún contenedor está en el 8081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno como te comentaba lo más fácil es hacerlo con `docker-compose`. En la página oficial de la imagen de [mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) ya te dan de ejemplo con `mongo` y `mongo-express`

Pero como veo que quieres con comandos.

```
// creamos la red
$ docker network create --driver=bridge mongo-net

// servidor de mongo
$ docker run --network mongo-net -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example --name mongo-db -d mongo

// mongo-express
$ docker run --network mongo-net -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo-db -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=example -p 8081:8081 mongo-express
```

http://localhost:8081/

Comment: Maldita sea, funciona. ¿Qué he fallado en mi intento?

Comment: Pues... si habías usado los mismo que te he puesto. No lo sé ¿error al escribir? Segunda opción es que lo mejor no creates la network antes? Ya te digo que me llevo un ratico más porque usando `--link` en el `mongo-express` me tiraba error de que no se podía conectar al mongo. También probé `docker network conect mongo-net contenedor-express` y luego levantar el contenedor de `mongo-express` y seguía dando error, y el contenedor de mongo funcionando correctamente, que yo me podía conectar desde el Robot3 al mongo. En fin, cosas del directo jajajja.

Comment: Y, sin embargo, lo has creado antes. Tengo otra pregunta. Cuando hago lo que tú haces puedo conectarme a mongo-express [pero mi script nodejs no puede conectarse. Pero cuando lo hago desde docker-compose puedo pero ya no puedo acceder a mongo-express](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478892/debe-sustituirse-la-imagen-de-un-contenedor-cuando-se-deprecia). ¿Crees que tengo un error en mi docker-compose.yaml?