# Con mongo y mongo-express creados con docker commands no puedo acceder con un servidor, con docker-compose puedo, sin acceso a mongo-express

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

*Todos los archivos utilisados aqui son de [este repositorio de gitlab](https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/techworld-js-docker-demo-app/-/tree/master/) creado para [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c-iBn73dDE&ab_channel=TechWorldwithNana) para aprender Docker.*

Tengo un servidor node.js que utilisa una base de datos mongodb y mongo-express para visualizarlo pero cuando utiliso los siguientes commandos para la siguiente arquitectura:

```
// creamos la red
$ docker network create --driver=bridge mongo-net

// servidor de mongo
$ docker run --network mongo-net -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example --name mongo-db -d mongo

// mongo-express
$ docker run --network mongo-net -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo-db -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=example -p 8081:8081 mongo-express
```

Puedo acceder a mongo-express y ver mi base de datos pero me contesta que la seleccion del server toma demasiado tiempo:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Docker\techworld-js-docker-demo-app\app>node server.js
(node:20904) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'count' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:20904) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:20904) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:20904) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
app listening on port 3000!
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Docker\techworld-js-docker-demo-app\app\server.js:61
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Docker\techworld-js-docker-demo-app\app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:878:9)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
    name: 'MongoNetworkError',
    errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
    [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Pero cuando utiliso este docker-file.yaml puedo acceder a la pagina pero no puedo acceder a mongo-express:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Docker\techworld-js-docker-demo-app>type docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  # my-app:
  # image: ${docker-registry}/my-app:1.0
  # ports:
  # - 3000:3000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      mongodb:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

Aqui esta el servidor server.js:

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let fs = require('fs');
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
  });

app.get('/profile-picture', function (req, res) {
  let img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "images/profile-1.jpg"));
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
});

// use when starting application locally
let mongoUrlLocal = "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017";

// use when starting application as docker container
let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb";

// pass these options to mongo client connect request to avoid DeprecationWarning for current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
let mongoClientOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

// "user-account" in demo with docker. "my-db" in demo with docker-compose
let databaseName = "my-db";

app.post('/update-profile', function (req, res) {
  let userObj = req.body;

  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlLocal, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);
    userObj['userid'] = 1;

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };
    let newvalues = { $set: userObj };

    db.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, {upsert: true}, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      client.close();
    });

  });
  // Send response
  res.send(userObj);
});

app.get('/get-profile', function (req, res) {
  let response = {};
  // Connect to the db
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlLocal, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };

    db.collection("users").findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response = result;
      client.close();

      // Send response
      res.send(response ? response : {});
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

y aqui esta el DockerFile:

```
FROM node:13-alpine

ENV MONGO_DB_USERNAME=admin \
    MONGO_DB_PWD=password

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY ./app /home/app

# set default dir so that next commands executes in /home/app dir
WORKDIR /home/app

# will execute npm install in /home/app because of WORKDIR
RUN npm install

# no need for /home/app/server.js because of WORKDIR
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Tambien intenté hacer el map para mongo-express sobre le port 8081-->8081 como en los commandos y deshacerme de `condition_on` que anadi con los consejos de OscarGarcia:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\Docker\techworld-js-docker-demo-app>docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml  up
Starting techworld-js-docker-demo-app_mongodb_1         ... done
Recreating techworld-js-docker-demo-app_mongo-express_1 ... done
Attaching to techworld-js-docker-demo-app_mongodb_1, techworld-js-docker-demo-app_mongo-express_1
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.437+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.439+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.441+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.442+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.444+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.444+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.444+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.447+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"d92121cab04b"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.447+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.2","gitVersion":"6d9ec525e78465dcecadcff99cce953d380fedc8","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.447+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.447+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.449+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.449+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:01.449+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=5792M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.355+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:355920][1:0x7f70e27dec80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 9 through 10"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.410+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:410416][1:0x7f70e27dec80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 10"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.508+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:508356][1:0x7f70e27dec80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 9/7168 to 10/256"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.620+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:620968][1:0x7f70e27dec80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 9 through 10"}}
mongo-express_1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express_1  | ------------------------
mongo-express_1  |
mongo-express_1  |
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.698+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:698305][1:0x7f70e27dec80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 10 through 10"}}
mongo-express_1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:27017
mongo-express_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
mongo-express_1  | }]
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:999:11
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
mongo-express_1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:283:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:313:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
mongo-express_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.769+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:769411][1:0x7f70e27dec80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.769+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:769496][1:0x7f70e27dec80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.787+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1629787382:787300][1:0x7f70e27dec80], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 509"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.822+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1373}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.822+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.825+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.827+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.838+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22178,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never'","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.841+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.841+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.842+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.843+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.848+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.849+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-08-24T06:43:02.849+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
techworld-js-docker-demo-app_mongo-express_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con depreciar? ¿Es una traducción de "deprecate" (desuso)? El problema que tienes es que no es capaz de conectarse a la base de datos: *MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server*. En particular, el código `ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:27017` corresponde a que la conexión fue rechazada. ¿Tienes levantada la base de datos? Es probable que necesites [crear las dependencias correctamente](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#depends_on) con `depends_on` o `condition` indicando `service_completed_successfully`.

Comment: Sí, exactamente, porque lo vi en las advertencias @OscarGarcia .
Pero no debe ser eso porque ayer pude conectarme y el error está en el aviso... He actualizado para poner todo el registro y parece que la base de datos MongoDB está bien leventada.¿Realmente crees que debo usar depends_on? Hasta que funciona sin ayer? Si no es así, supongo que lo añado al contenedor mongo-express?

Comment: Posiblemente te ha estado funcionando hasta que la base de datos está empezando a tardar más en levantar que tu aplicación. Tu aplicación cae en cuanto no puede conectar con la base de datos, si capturas la excepción e intentas de nuevo la conexión pasados unos segundos no tendrás ese problema. Por lo pronto te aconsejo indicar el orden en el que deben desplegarse los contenedores, ya que tu aplicación no permite el despliegue paralelo (cae si la base de datos es más lenta en arrancar).

Comment: De hecho, solo tienes que mirar el registro de arranque del servidor mongo, cuya última linea, después de la caída de mongo-express, es `"ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections"`. Eso indica que mongo comenzó a admitir conexiones después de haber caído mongo-express por culpa de no poder conectarse a ella.

Comment: Listo @OscarGarcia . Acabo de actualizar docker-compose.yaml pero sigo sin poder conectarme y no tengo más logs. (Por lo tanto puedo acceder a la mia app con node server.js y modificar la base de datos)

Comment: ¿Qué te sale ahora en el registro de despliegue del servicio?

Comment: Acabo de anadirlos @OscarGarcia Digame si te falta qualciera cosa

Comment: Me supongo que todo lo que hace la imagen de node es `FROM node:14 \n copy . . \n RUN npm i \n RUN npm start` (Donde `\n` es como un enter, pero en los comentarios no se puede), ¿no? He copiado y pegado tu docker-compose y lo que cambié fue `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/` y luego en el node debes hacer `mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/database?authSource=admin', {useNewUrlParser: true});`

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY index.js ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    container_name: nodeapp
    volumes:
      - ./index.js:/usr/src/app/index.js
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - mongo-express
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo_db
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo_express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/
    depends_on:
      - mongo
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

index.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const port = 5000;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/database?authSource=admin', {useNewUrlParser: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('connection error', err);
});

db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connection to DB successful');
});

const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
    fluffy.save();
    res.send("HOLA");
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Express server is ready");
});
```

En este caso lo único que estoy haciendo es que al ir a `http://localhost:5000/` responda un `HOLA` y además añada un nuevo `Kitten` a mi base de datos, luego en `http://localhost:8081/` verás `database` y dentro `name: fluffy`.

En cuanto a tus errores, pues no veo tu `Dockerfile` ni tampoco tu código de `JS`. El error de `timeout` es cuando la URL de la conexión es errónea probable tengas puesto `localhost:27017`, pero debería ser **el nombre de tu servicio en el docker-compose del mongo**.

Y del `docker-compose` solamente lo que ya te comenté antes, también cambié el `depends_on` que a mi me tira error de sintaxis ¿A ti no te tira ese error? Hice un copy/paste del tuyo.

Bueno, suerte!